# Open another page in Dialog box

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I am trying to use [Dialog box](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

In my add-in, I have two buttons `openGoogle` and `openStackoverflow` which link to `openDialog("https://www.google.com")` and `openDialog("https://www.stackoverlfow.com")`:

```
function openDialog(url) {
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 1100, width: 1000 }, 
            function (result) {
                console.log("here")
                dialog = result.value;
            }
        )
}
```

First, I open one dialog by clicking on `openGoogle`, then if I click on `openStackoverflow`, `here` is displayed again, however the dialog does NOT go to stackoverflow.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that you could successfully open `https://www.google.com`? You shouldn't be able to - unless your app is hosted on the Google domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins):

> the page, controller method, or other resource that is passed to the
>   displayDialogAsync method must be in the same domain as the host page.

If you need to get users to another domain, you can do this by first opening a dialog to a page within your add-in that then immediately redirects them to the external domain using `window.location.href = "https://www.stackoverlfow.com";`